# JSON Data-structure in C++ and querying it

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, json

As a personal challenge I want to implement a C++ JSON Parser. As part of that I have implemented the following Types/Data-structures and a way of querying them.

To represent the type of an individual JSON attribute I defined the following std::variant and aliased it as JSONType. My thought behind using an std::variant is that when dealing with a JSON attribute I know that it must be one of the following types, but I can't exactly know which type before parsing the attribute.

Right now I am not concerned about "null" and "arrays with different types".

```
using JSONType = std::variant
<
    bool,
    int,
    float,
    double,
    std::string,

    std::vector<bool>,
    std::vector<int>,
    std::vector<float>,
    std::vector<double>,
    std::vector<std::string>
>;
```

To represent a JSON object I defined the struct JSONObject. My reasoning behind the attributes member is that for every JSON attribute I have a string as it's key and the value is either a single JSONType (bool, int, ...) or another JSONObject that recursively repeats this structure.

The query function "getIf(keys)" expects a template type T, which is the type of data that the user expects to get out of the query. keys is a sequence of strings , where the first n-1 strings describe the path of nested JSONObjects down the tree to which the attribute resides that we want to return. So the nth string is the name of that attribute.

```
struct JSONObject
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::variant<JSONType, JSONObject>> attributes;

    template <class T>
    T* getIf(std::vector<std::string> const& keys)
    {
        JSONObject* temp = this;

        // Go to JSONObject where last keys attribute resides.
        for (int i = 0; i < (keys.size() - 1); ++i)
        {
            temp = &std::get<JSONObject>(temp->attributes[keys[i]]);
        }

        // Find the attribute that we actually want to return,
        // which is the attribute that is pointed to by
        // the last given key.
        JSONType& variant = std::get<JSONType>(temp->attributes[keys[keys.size() - 1]]);

        // Check if the given template type T is the same type
        // that the attribute that we want to return has.
        if (auto* value = std::get_if<T>(&variant))
        {
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            return nullptr;
        }
    }
};
```

The following is an example instatiation and query of a JSONObject that represents the following json file and should result in a tree-like structure like the diagram shows.

```
    JSONObject o
    { // Initialization brackets
        { // unordered_map brackets
            { "boolean", std::variant<JSONType, JSONObject>(true) }, // map entry brackets
            { "nested_object", std::variant<JSONType, JSONObject>(JSONObject
                {
                    {
                        { "float", std::variant<JSONType, JSONObject>(3.14123f)},
                        { "nested_object_2", std::variant<JSONType, JSONObject>(JSONObject
                            {
                                {
                                    { "string", std::variant<JSONType, JSONObject>(std::string("Hello World"))}
                                }
                            }
                        )},
                        { "numbers", std::variant<JSONType, JSONObject>(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) }
                    }
                } 
            )}
        }
    };

    bool boolean = *o.getIf<bool>({ "boolean" });
    float flo = *o.getIf<float>({ "nested_object", "float" });
    std::string string = *o.getIf<std::string>({ "nested_object", "nested_object_2", "string" });
    std::vector<int> numbers = *o.getIf<std::vector<int>>({ "nested_object", "numbers" });

        {
            "boolean": true,
            "nested_object":
            {
                "float": 3.14123f,
                "nested_object_2":
                {
                    "string": "Hello World"
                },
                "numbers": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            }
        }
```

[image: Diagram]

I am interested in the quality of this solution and alternative solutions.
Thanks !

Comment: Here is an alternative: [ThorsSerializer](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer/blob/master/doc/example1.md)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't like this:

```
using JSONType = std::variant
<
    bool,
    int,
    float,
    double,
    std::string,

    std::vector<bool>,
    std::vector<int>,
    std::vector<float>,
    std::vector<double>,
    std::vector<std::string>
>;
```

That's not really what the type looks like. The array (Vector) can have any JSON type as a member. I think a better version would be:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

enum JsonType {Null, Obj, Vec, Bool, Int, Double, String};
class   Json;
struct JsonObj
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Json>   members;
};
using   JsonVec   = std::vector<Json>;
union JsonUnion
{
    JsonUnion() {null_ = nullptr;}
    ~JsonUnion(){}
    void*       null_;
    JsonObj     object_;
    JsonVec     array_;
    bool        bool_;
    int         int_;
    double      real_;
    std::string string_;
};
class Json
{

    JsonType     type;
    JsonUnion    data;
    public:
        Json()
            : type(Null)
            , data()
        {}
};

int main()
{
    Json    value;
}
```

---

The get function assumes you only have objects. You should be able to handle de-referencing arrays. But that requires two types of get parameter (integer and string).

```
using Access = std::variant<int, std::string>;

template <class T>
T* getIf(std::vector<Access> const& keys)
```

---

Also why are you returning a pointer?

```
T* getIf()
```

Memory management is hard. That is why C got such a bad reputation for being hard. Java tried to solve this with the garbage collector (which just caused more issues with runtime running). C++ solved the problem by introducing "Automated Fine Grain Deterministic Memory Management" also know as "Smart Pointers". This is how memory management is done consisely and reliabily in modern C++.

```
std::unqiue_ptr<T> getIf()
```

---

Using `class` in the template is a bit old school.

```
template <class T>
T* getIf(
```

Sure it is technically valid. But most people use `typename`. It has exactly the same meaning to the compiler. But to the human it implies that `T` can be any type (not just a class Type).

---

If you are "getting" something from an object then I would normally expect that this would not alter the object. I notice that your `getIf()` is not `const`. You probably did this because it does not compile with `const`. This is because you use `operator[]` on the unordered map.

```
temp = &std::get<JSONObject>(temp->attributes[keys[i]]);
                                             ^       ^
```

When looking a value in a unordered_map (or map) and you use the square braces then if the key does not exist it is added to the structure. This is probably not what you want.

I would change this so it uses a `find`. If the object does not have the appropriate key then you have a serious issue and I would throw an exception:

```
auto find = temp->attributes.find(keys[i]);
if (find == temp->attributes.end()) {
    throw "Bad Member Name";
}

temp = &std::get<JSONObject>(find->second);
```

---

Comment: For clarification, by "The get function assumes you only have objects. You should be able to handle de-referencing arrays. But that requires two types of get parameter (integer and string)." you mean that if I have the attribute 
`"numbers": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, I should be able to return an individual value of that array ? Maybe I misunderstand you.

Comment: @MoritzSchäfer: `getIf<int>("nested_object", "numbers", 3)` should be able to return the 3 element in "numbers" that is in the member "nested_object" inside your object.

Comment: You are using a union for JSONUnion instead of an std::variant because you can't do null = nullptr; with std::variant ?

Comment: @MoritzSchäfer I used a `union` because I don't know how to use `std::variant` it's not something I have found the need for yet. Note: I don't use `union` often either (about twice in thirty years).